# What if no entry translated with Transcribe?

Tags: transcribe

I'm quite new in EE so my question can be trivial.

What to do if one (or more) entry is not translated? If I have translation for English but change language to Deutsch for example - I got an error. I'd like to get the point where if I change the language and do not have translation for any entry the default language will be shown.

I try to work with this code but it doesn't work:

```
{if title == ""}
{exp:transcribe:language name="english"}{title}{/exp:transcribe}
{/if}
```

I use Transcribe and EE 3.0.4.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a language switch link on the page? You can add conditional code around the language switcher so it would only appear if there is an entry in the other language.